# SQL Query To CoreData Format

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sqlite, core-data

```
Select * from ZCONTACTSENTITY where '917878878778' like '%' || zcontact_number || '%';
```

- ZCONTACTSENTITY --(Table Name)
- zcontact_number --(Field Name)
- '917878878778' --(Parameter)

I Checked this query directly in SQLlite Database and it returns perfect result which i need. But i want it in **CoreData Format**, because in my iOS Project i am using CoreData. 
I tried lots of thing like (LIKE, MATCHES, CONTAINS) but non of them resulted to me.

Comment: What is the field value you are trying to match against?

Comment: If you want to know how to configure a Core Data fetch, you should describe how your data model is structured. Working backwards from SQL is doing it the hard way. What does your model look like, and how do you need to fetch data from your persistent store?

Comment: Ok, i can provide 1 case which match my requirement...    Suppose x1 Row, with (zcontact_number) Field having "7878878778" value And my parameter is "917878878778". So in return i must get x1 row as a result.    I hope this can help more to solve my query.

Comment: Did you try: '917878878778' contains contact_number

Comment: Yes, i tried but no result.